# Picture Alignment with Numbered List (Android)

Tags: java, pdf, formatting, itext

I have a pdf file with different pages that I'm trying to merge into ONE PDF page. 
So this list of pages are merged together and numbered. 
For example :

```
1. Page1
2. Page2
```

till all the separate pages are numbered and merged into one whole document.

### the PROBLEM here is, that the numbers appear bottom aligned. I cannot get the numbers to appear at the top of the text.

[image]

---

Here is the snippet

```
 canvas.addTemplate(page, 1f, 0 , 0, 1, 100, pos);
canvas.beginText();
canvas.setTextMatrix(90, (float) ((pos)-0.5*CurPsize));
canvas.showText(m+"."+" ");
canvas.endText();
```

where ,
m=1 // number of pages counter initialized at 1

Rectangle r=reader.getPageSize(m)

CurPsize=(r.getTop()-r.getBottom());

pos=pos-CurPsize

.

I have attached the pdf file here. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4scqcWd2Ci0X1JpSi15Q1FkVDQ/edit?usp=sharing

This is the file I want to merge with numbering

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to correspond with your question. Have you tried creating a 2-column table with the numbers in one column and the images in the other?

Comment: The images are not of a fixed size. The numbers need to be correspondingly placed according to the size of the image, just how bullet points work. If I do make a 2 column table, will I able to make the two data align with each other accordingly? Sorry, very new to this. A little detailed help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a more mathematical approach to it, find the height of the image by using getTop()-getBottom().

Then , you should shift the images down by that amount of height Downwards. This will ensure that it is aligned properly.